# image slider code, can anyone elaborate it

Tags: javascript

hi there iam new to javascript and i wanted an imageslider, so came across the code mentioned below. Can anyone explain this to me, especially the code within **. I would really appreciate it, thanks.

```
var blocks = $(".blocks li");
var image = $(".imageholder li");
var imgholder = $(".imageholder");
var imagew = $(".imageholder li").width();
var speed = 300;


blocks.removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');

**blocks.click(function() {
var target = $(this).index();**

**imgholder.animate({"left": "-"+imagew*target+"px"}, speed);**

blocks.removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blocks.click` means when you click on an element li within an element with class of `blocks`,
execute the function in the parameters.

```
var target = $(this).index();
```

means getting the number of the element, clicking on the second element will assign 2 to target.

```
imgholder.animate({"left": "-"+imagew*target+"px"}, speed)
```

will animate the img to the left, at a speed of speed and to the position -Ypx, where Y is equal to the `imagewidth` times the `target`

Comment: `var imagew = $(".imageholder li").width();`
this variable collects the width of list items right?